# How to compile with clang for Thumb-only CPU?

Tags: gcc, arm, clang, thumb

I have tried `-mthumb`, it looks like the sources just get compiled for ARM. I have tried triple `--target=thumbv7-linux-gnueabihf`, but the build system just skips compiling the project. I know they somehow compile for Thumb-only target with the same build system (perhaps configuring in a different way, different target, options etc), but I can't reproduce so far the problem where my ARM assembly fails to compile on a Thumb-only CPU.
I've looked through `gcc` options for Thumb and got only the above ideas.

EDIT: it seems they compile for Thumb-only CPU on a Thumb-only CPU, so it is automatically selected as the default target. But I am cross-compiling from x86_64-Windows to ARM-Linux (and I want Thumb-Linux).

EDIT2: more specifically, I am trying to reproduce the following error in my assembly file:

```
Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- push {r1-r3,lr}
```

Comment: Typically for gcc I see `-mcpu=xxx` or `-march=xxx` and it seems like those might be needed. Are you cross compiling for a Linux target on the Thumb-only micro? If bare metal, I believe the target is supposed to be `--target=arm-none-eabi`, but again, that's gcc not clang.

Comment: @rjp, I don't think it should be bare-metal. In fact I need any Thumb-only CPU. To be able to test the result, I need it to work on ARM-Ubuntu under QEmu.

Comment: Thumb or Thumb-2? For Thumb, it looks like you'd probably want `-march=armv4t`. For Thumb-2, `-march=armv7-m`. I think the issue you'll run into is cross compiling a Linux executable on Windows. I would imagine you would need to link against Linux libraries.

Comment: @rjp, I don't know, I can guess it's Thumb2 because just Thumb seems too old. I already have Linux binaries from Linaro, and they were linking ok for ARM CPU mode.

Comment: Take a look here: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html

Comment: The reason I asked about Thumb vs. Thumb-2, is that I haven't heard of running Linux (only uCLinux) on any of the Cortex-M's, but I believe there are Linux ports for ARM7TDMI (Thumb only).

Comment: Yes, I looked at that page, I think I have got what I could from it. Following your suggestion, I am now testing with `-mcpu=cortex-a15 -mthumb --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf`, and I plan to try `-march` then.

Comment: _"it looks like the sources just get compiled for ARM"_ - how exactly does it look that way? If you're targeting a Thumb-capable CPU/architecture, and passing `-mthumb`, then at least _your_ C code should get compiled to Thumb, but if you're then linking it against libraries full of ARM code, and disassembling the result, you might be misled. There are far too many variables here to guess at without a clear problem description and, ideally, a reproducible example.

Comment: @Notlikethat , I have an ARM assembly file, which contains instructions missing in Thumb/Thumb2, but the file gets successfully compiled. So I cannot reproduce the following: `Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor -- push {r1-r3,lr}`. I've included this in the question.

Comment: ...that's a ridiculous error :/ `push {r1-r3,lr}` is and _always has been_ a perfectly valid Thumb instruction. Even back in the old days when it wasn't even a valid ARM instruction (`push...` only became an official architectural alias of `stmdb r13!...` with ARMv6T2 and the introduction of UAL).

Comment: @Notlikethat, very interesting turn, I am indeed getting strange results. With `-mcpu=cortex-a15 -march=armv7-m -mthumb --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf` the code still compiles successfully in my environment. But I know my assembly file is ARM, it never supported Thumb, so I am better off getting a compile error for it in Thumb than getting it silently converted into Thumb, I think. The problem is that I can't reproduce this...

Comment: If your assembly file is truly using some of the very small handful of instructions which only have ARM encodings, or any of the broader range of operands and addressing modes which certain ARM encodings have over Thumb encodings of the same instruction, then it _cannot_ get "silently converted into Thumb" because it will be unassemblable. And if it's not, then there's no reason it shouldn't work as Thumb code. Thus either way your concern doesn't appear to be valid, and it seems more likely that this all just stems from some configuration triggering a bug in Clang's integrated assembler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling to ARM I get "Error: attempt to use an ARM instruction on a Thumb-only processor"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515677/compiling-to-arm-i-get-error-attempt-to-use-an-arm-instruction-on-a-thumb-only)